# Hamburger menu to close upon clicking links

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, hamburger-menu

I have created a simple Hamburger menu I would like to close when you click on one of the links but I do not know how to do this. My HTML is:

```
<nav>

            <div class="nav_top">

                <div class="nav_logo">
                    <img src="images/nav_logo.png">
                </div>  <!-- end of nav_logo -->

            </div> <!-- end of nav_top -->

            <div class="hamburger" id="hamburger">
                    <img src="images/hamburger.svg">
                </div>      

            <div class="list-items">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#welcome">WELCOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#venue">VENUE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#accommodation">ACCOMMODATION</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#gifts">GIFTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#weekend">WEEKEND</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#RSVP">RSVP</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav> <!-- end of navigation section -->
```

My jQuery is:

```
jQuery(function($){
         $( '.hamburger' ).click(function(){
         $('.list-items').toggleClass('expand')
         })
    })
```

Is there something simple I can add to the jQuery to get this to work? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try using a bootstrap dropdown, it has that functionality inherently built in: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

example:

```
<ul class="user-dropdown navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-lg fa-navicon" title="Menu"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-header user-dropdown-header">
        Header
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/index" class="link">All</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="/new" class="link">New</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

no js hacks required

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a listener on the links in the list-items div, so you can close the div when any of them are clicked:

```
$( '.list-items a' ).on("click", function(){
    $('.list-items').hide();
});
```

Comment: sorry, do you mean add something into the HTML code? Also, where do I add the jQuery code - like this?

    jQuery(function($){
             $( '.hamburger' ).click(function(){
             $('.list-items').toggleClass('expand')
             })
             $( '.list-items a' ).on("click", function(){
       $('.list-items').hide();
   });
        })

Comment: You don't need to change any html. Just place the javascript anywhere in your script area, but not nested in your other code. So, just add this js below your existing js code and you should be fine. What this code does is wait for a click event to happen on any of the A tags inside the list-items div. See http://api.jquery.com/on/